# Ubuntu 12.04 - PC freezes after 10 minutes of inactivity

Tags: nvidia

If I don't use my computer after 10 minutes, it tries to sleep but just freezes. Nothing works and I have to reboot losing all of my unsaved programs. I could change it to never sleep but is there a fix for this? I heard that this might be a bug. Also this just started happening when I changed my video card and put a new Nvidia Geforce 610 in my computer. Should i upgrade to 12.10?

thanks,

Darwin

Answer (score 0):

As the problem started when you changed your graphics card, it seems obvious that there may be something relevant to the graphic cards drivers. Ubuntu needs additional proprietary drivers for many Nvidia cards. Did you adjust that when you changed the card? I would suggest that you check
 [a tutorial on how to install the latest ones](http://www.techlw.com/2012/03/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-1204.html)